# Tensorflow new graph vs default graph

Tags: tensorflow

Why would you do this:

```
graph = tf.Graph.__init__()
```

Versus:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

I don't understand the purpose of a default graph.

Answer (score 2):

A graph defines the computations. It will not compute, it cannot hold any values.
A graph is like a TODO: list.

You may use more than one graphs (created with `tf.Graph()` in the same process, but one is the default.

Note you will have to use different sessions for each graph, but each graph can be used in multiple sessions.

Even more, a session allows executing graphs or part of graphs. It allocates resources (on a single or multiple machines) for that and holds the actual values of intermediate results and variables.

You can create a session with `tf.Session`, and be sure to use a context manager or `tf.Session.close()`, because all resources of the session are saved.

Answer (score -1):

`graph = tf.Graph.__init__()` will instantiate a new (and therefore empty) TensorFlow graph object, while `graph = tf.get_default_graph()` will get you the default graph you are working on.

More information on the official [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/basic_usage):

> The TensorFlow Python library has a default graph to which ops constructors add nodes. The default graph is sufficient for many applications. See the Graph class documentation for how to explicitly manage multiple graphs.

Comment: Why would you use one over the other? What's an example use case for one vs the other?

Comment: Good question. Also what is default graph when one is restoring model? How can I restore in particular graph and not into default graph.